# Powershell command to fetch a value from Invoke-Webrequest o/p

Tags: powershell

I am trying to fetch the "AVI_API_VERSION:" number  from  "RawContent' in the below output.

```
$Response

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11"/><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><title>Avi Vantage Con…
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2022 12:40:17 GMT
                    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    Vary: Accept
                    Vary: Cookie
                    Vary: Origin
                    Cache-Control: max-age=0
                    AVI_API_VERSION: 16_4_2
                    Set-Cookie…
Headers           : {[Date, System.String[]], [Transfer-Encoding, System.String[]], [Connection, System.String[]], [Vary, System.String[]]…}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
RawContentLength  : 2357
RelationLink      : {}
```

While trying to use $Response.RawContent -split "[`r`n]" | select-string  "AVI_API_VERSION", getting the below o/p. Is there a powershell command to fetch only the version number from the below o/p

AVI_API_VERSION: 16_4_2

Comment: There's no need for groping `RawContent` since what you've got there is a header that's available through `Headers`.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an easier way to do this (see what [Jeroen Mosterd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71512792/powershell-command-to-fetch-a-value-from-invoke-webrequest-o-p#comment126395427_71512792) commented), but you can get the wanted info using regex:

```
$apiVersion = ([regex]'(?si)AVI_API_VERSION:\s(\d+_\d+_\d+)').Match($Response.RawContent).Groups[1].Value
```

Or use `-replace`

```
$apiVersion = $Response.RawContent -replace '(?si).*AVI_API_VERSION:\s(\d+_\d+_\d+).*', '$1'
```

Regex details:

```
(?si)                  Match the remainder of the regex with the options: dot matches newline (s); case insensitive (i)
AVI_API_VERSION:       Match the characters “AVI_API_VERSION:” literally
\s                     Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
(                      Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d                  Match a single digit 0..9
      +                Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   _                   Match the character “_” literally
   \d                  Match a single digit 0..9
      +                Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   _                   Match the character “_” literally
   \d                  Match a single digit 0..9
      +                Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks much for your help!